# How to install EventDispatcher in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

I am not able to get how can i install EventDispatcher in symfony2.
I mean in which folder ihave to extract those contents

This is the official docs

https://github.com/symfony/EventDispatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't extract anything, use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) instead.